# java compiler error with generics and an iterator

Tags: java, iterator

I have the following code (Yes, I know the iterator is implemented incorrectly.  This is an exam question I'm writing):

```
public class MyList<Integer> extends ArrayList<Integer> {
  public void noOdds() {
    MyIterator<Integer> iter = this.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) { 
      if (iter.next() % 2 == 1)
        iter.remove();
    }   
  } 

  public MyIterator<Integer> iterator() {
    return new MyIterator<Integer>(this);
  } 

  public class MyIterator<Integer> implements Iterator<Integer> {
    List<Integer> data;
    int size;
    int position;

    MyIterator(List<Integer> data) {
      this.data = data;
      this.size = data.size();
      this.position = 0;
    } 

    public boolean hasNext() {
      if (this.position < this.size)
        return true;
      else
        return false;
    }   

    public Integer next() {
      Integer tmp = this.data.get(this.position);
      this.position++;
      return tmp;
    }

    public void remove() {
      if (this.position == 0)
        throw new IllegalStateException("next hasn't been called yet");
      this.data.remove(this.position - 1);
    }
  }
}
```

When I compile, it won't auto box the Integer for modulo op, and I get

MyList.java:9: error: bad operand types for binary operator '%'
            if (iter.next() % 2 == 1)

first type:  Integer

second type: int

If I change `iter.next()` to `iter.next().intValue()`, I get

MyList.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
if (iter.next().intValue() % 2 == 1)

symbol:   method intValue()

location: class Object

However, if I change

```
 public class MyList<Integer>...
```

to

```
 public class MyList
```

then the errors go away.

Thoughts on what's going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here,

```
public class MyList<Integer> extends ArrayList<Integer> {
                //  ^ here
```

you are declaring a type variable `Integer` which shadows the `java.lang.Integer` type.

Anywhere within the type body where you refer to `Integer`, you are referring to the type variable rather than the `java.lang.Integer` type.

The various numerical operators do not apply to random types (which is what your type variable is), they only work with primitive numeric types and their wrapper classes. Therefore you can't use them with operands of the type of your type variable.