# Sorting the linked list using Collection.sort

Tags: java, collections, linked-list, timetable

```
import java.util.*;

class MyComp<Subject> implements Comparator<Subject> {
    public int compare(Subject s1, Subject s2) {
        return s1.year - s2.year;
    }
}

public class Subject {
    String subjectID;
    int sem;
    String dept;
    public int year;
    String subjectName;
    int theortical;
    int practical;
    int tutorial;
}
```

I am facing a problem while compiling `cannot find symbol s1.year`. Same thing for `s2.year`.

Comment: `class MyComp<Subject>` defines generic type with name `Subject` which has nothing to do with `Subject` class. Your code is same as `class MyComp<T> implements Comparator<T>` where you are trying to access `year` from `T` type. Remove that `<Subject>` from `MyComp<Subject>`. Now where is that duplicate...

Comment: Other potential duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852512/java-compiler-error-with-generics-and-an-iterator

Comment: related: [What does a “Cannot find symbol” compilation error mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)